# How to group data in object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object

I am receiving data in this format:

```
{2013-09-13 22:55:56 UTC=>1, 2013-09-15 13:14:19 UTC=>1, 2013-09-16 13:05:39 UTC=>1, 2013-09-16 19:12:44 UTC=>1}
```

I would need to `group` them according to day, to this shape:

```
{2013-09-13=>1, 2013-09-15=>1, 2013-09-16=>2}
```

How to do this in Ruby?

Comment: The examples are not valid ruby code.. So how shall it work?

Comment: You're supposed to provide code. What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would also work

```
 hsh = {"2013-09-13 22:55:56 UTC"=>1, "2013-09-15 13:14:19 UTC"=>1, "2013-09-16 13:05:39 UTC"=>1, "2013-09-16 19:12:44 UTC"=>1}

 hsh.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h,(k,v)| h[k.to_date.to_s] += v; h}
 # => {"2013-09-13"=>1, "2013-09-15"=>1, "2013-09-16"=>2}
```

remove the `.to_s` if you want the keys to be Date objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would this way :

```
require 'date'

hsh = {'2013-09-13 22:55:56 UTC'=>1, '2013-09-15 13:14:19 UTC'=>1, '2013-09-16 13:05:39 UTC' =>1, '2013-09-16 19:12:44 UTC'=>1}

hsh.map{|k,v| Date.parse(k).to_s}.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|a,h| h[a]+=1 }
# => {"2013-09-13"=>1, "2013-09-15"=>1, "2013-09-16"=>2}
hsh.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|(k,_),h| h[Date.parse(k).to_s]+=1 }
# => {"2013-09-13"=>1, "2013-09-15"=>1, "2013-09-16"=>2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are given just one long string:

```
str = "2013-09-13 22:55:56 UTC=>1, 2013-09-15 13:14:19 UTC=>1,
2013-09-16 13:05:39 UTC=>1, 2013-09-16 19:12:44 UTC=>1"
```

this would work:

```
result = [] 
str.scan(/\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d/).group_by {|i| i}.each {|key,value| result << "#{key}=>#{value.size.to_s}"}
result
```

Could replace `group_by {|i| i}` with `group_by(&:dup)`...